# UPDATE statement returning error when using the Cassandra Node.js driver

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax-node-driver

I'm getting a problem when I try to update a data using this node.js script, using cassandra-driver package :

```
pool.execute(`UPDATE cool.dmpt SET points = ${newpoint}, cooldown = true WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`)
```

I am getting a huge error which says:

```
error.noHostAvaialableError
.
.
.
info: 'Represents an error when a query cannot be performed because no host is available or could be reached by the driver'
```

Other queries are executed well, but UPDATE query is giving the error :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is missing a few details. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Missing `await` before executing query.